# Converting milliseconds to ISODate before saving to mongodb on the fly (mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a stream of data coming in a json format with a timestamp in milliseconds. I would like to ask if there is a built in way to convert the milliseconds into the ISODate format on the fly. So ideally I would like to be able to do this during the schema creation step.

An example of on the fly preprocessing

```
     let schema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String, age: Number, time: Number}, { 
        timestamps: { 
        createdAt: 'createdAtCustom', 
        updatedAt: 'updatedAtCustom'  }
        })
```

In the above snippet, we can see that I created a schema with a predefined timestamp for the creation and modification of a document.

I was wondering if there is a similar way to convert a value before it gets saved to the database.

Purchase something like this

(pseudocode)

```
Schema({name: String, age: Number, time: new Date(Number)})
```

Comment: You appear to be simply looking for the `Date` schema type `Schema({name: String, age: Number, time: Date })`. Mongoose "casts" values it receives to the types specified in the schema. For `Date` that means any valid date string or numeric value will be cast as a BSON Date.

Comment: Thank you Neil Lunn, I have converted the epoch timestamp the way you mentioned in your comment but now I have this: 1970-01-18T16:09:14.931Z . Not sure what kind of one off error I am looking at . Any idea what might be wrong here? Thanks again

PS: example of passed timestamp value 1526953734

Comment: Do you come from a PHP background? That's not a valid value for "milliseconds since epoch". It's "seconds from epoch". Typically comes of of `strtotime()` of PHP. It means whatever is exporting the JSON is doing it wrong. If you are pressed for time, look at ways to either append three zeroes to the end of that value in the file, or multiply the timestamp values by 1000 before passing the document for insertion. Probably better to fix the original export if you can.

Comment: @NeilLunn unfortunately, I cannot fix the original export, maybe there is a way to add the multiplication in the Schema?

Comment: Not in the schema. You're looking in the wrong place `Read file -> Parse JSON -> Change Object -> Insert to MongoDB`. Do it after you parse it